# Main activity design too busy

Tags: android

I have a main activity that contains many buttons.  I don't want to have a list of buttons like this. I know this looks bad, only cause I threw this together to show you what I have. As you can see, I really don't even have enough room. I don't want a `scrollView` in my main Activity. Does anyone have suggestions on building my activity to look sleek and simple?

[image]

Comment: not without knowing what it does and what it currently looks like :)

Comment: Ok take a look. Does this explain better?

Comment: How about using layout_weight ?
It may help with creation of percent based items height.

Comment: You could use a grid layout with big icons.

Comment: Thats a good idea. I just can't draw icons for the life of me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to put the buttons in a [NavigationDrawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) and display only the most important info in the content of the `Activity` or one of the other screens as the starting point and the user can navigate from here through the `NavigationDrawer`

If you don't like this approach you could also try putting the buttons in an [ActionBar Spinner](https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/spinners.html) as a list. This way you'll have one of the "Fight Cards", "Buy Tickets", etc screen as the starting point and the user can navigate from here through the `Spinner`

I don't know exactly what you're displaying in the application so I cannot decide what is the best solution for your problem, you'll have to figure that out yourself.